# Autenticación con tablas diferentes en laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5, autenticación

estoy realizando la autenticación multiple en laravel basandome en este enlace
*https://medium.com/hello-laravel/multiple-authentication-system-laravel-5-4-ac94c759638a*,
solo que en mi caso ya no realizo las tablas ya que estan dadas y los campos también, terminando al ingresar los datos solo me devuelve al login, y no marca algun error, claro, no es completamente igual ya que son campos diferentes. Modifiqué los diferentes archivos en mi proyecto

**Modelo**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
use Notifiable;
protected $table    = 'PERSONAL_NOMINA';
protected $fillable = ['NOMBRE', 'USUARIO', 'CONTRASENA'];
protected $hidden   = ['CONTRASENA', 'remember_token'];

public function getAuthPassword()
{
    return $this->CONTRASENA;
}
}
```

**LoginController**

```
      $this->validate($request, [
    $this->username() => 'required',
    'contrasena' => 'required',
]);
  // Attempt to log the user in
  if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt([$this->username() => $request->USUARIO, 'CONTRASENA' => $request->CONTRASENA], $request->remember)) {
    // if successful, then redirect to their intended location
    return redirect()->intended(route('admin.dashboard'));
  }
  // if unsuccessful, then redirect back to the login with the form data
  return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('usuario', 'remember'));
}
public function logout()
{
    Auth::guard('admin')->logout();
    return redirect()->route('admin.auth.login');
}
```

**AdminController**

```
public function __construct() {

    $this->middleware('auth:admin');

}

public function index() {

    return view('admin.inicio');

}
```

los demás archivos están igual.

Answer (score 0):

Asegurate de tener estas funciones en tu modelo

```
    public function getAuthPassword() {
        return $this->CONTRASENA;
    }

    public function getRememberToken() {
        return $this->remember_token;
    }

    public function setRememberToken($token) {
        $this->remember_token = $token;
    }

    public function getRememberTokenName() {
        return 'remember_token';
    }

    public function getPasswordAttribute() {
        return $this->CONTRASENA;
    }

    public function setPasswordAttribute($CONTRASENA) {
        $this->CONTRASENA = Hash::make($CONTRASENA);
    }
```

Luego, al hacer `attempt` SIEMPRE debes mandar un indice `password` de esta forma

```
Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['USUARIO' => $request->USUARIO, 'password' => $request->CONTRASENA], $request->remember)
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, agregué en el modelo lo que pusiste y cambie en el controlador pero sigue igual, no me marca nada solo al tratar de acceder me regresa al login, en que parte estaré mal?

Comment: En la funcion login ejecuta `dd(request())` para revisar si estas dirigiendote a la ruta correcta

Comment: me redirige a la misma ruta, o sea la del login

Comment: Esto quiere decir que el form no te lleva a tu controlador, revisa las rutas